# Кроссплатформенность прагм среды разработки

Tags: c++, ide, clion, кроссплатформенность

Являются ли прагмы из `CLion` "безопасными"?

В частности, могу ли я использовать:

```
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "OCUnusedMacroInspection"
```

, и рассчитывать, что другие IDE будут собирать код с такими прагмами без ошибок?

Comment: Думаю, можно рассчитывать, что другие компиляторы просто проигнорируют (вероятно, с warning'ом) незнакомые им #pragmы.

Answer (score 2):

> [**[cpp.pragma]/1**](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pragma#1)
>
> ... Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.

Компиляторы должны игнорировать неизвестные им `#pragma`.

Проверил крупные компиляторы - ошибок не возникает, только предупреждения. Если не включать "считать любое предупреждение за ошибку", то пробем быть не должно.

GCC 9.2 с `-std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`:

```
<source>:1: warning: ignoring #pragma ide diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

Clang 9.0.0 с `-std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`:

```
<source>:1:9: warning: unknown pragma ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

MSVC 19.12 без флажков:

```
<source>(1): warning C4068: unknown pragma
```

ICC 19.0.1 с `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`:

```
<source>(1): warning #161: unrecognized #pragma
```

Answer (score 1):

Вся идея директивы `#pragma` заключается в том, что предоставляемая ею специфическая функциональность не переносима между реализациями. Она для того и существует в языке.

Поэтому проверить поддержку конкретных директив внутри `#pragma` можно только путем чтения документации конкретного целевого компилятора.

А будет ли другой компилятор (проигнорировавший неизвестную ему прагму) собирать код без ошибок, зависит от сути этой прагмы.